# Using the word 'for' in a sentence

Tags: prepositions

I am searching for an answer to the use of 'for' in the following sentences:

1. I would like for you to keep it.
2. Life was too weird for Jeff to return to class.

I've found some answers. For example: 'because' or 'since' and also as a conjunction instead of as a preposition and I've seen it described as an intensifier. But I don't think it's any of those here. Is it a prepositional phrase?

If so, why is it possible to take out 'for' in the first sentence but not in the second?

Comment: _Too [adjective] for_ is just a standard construction. "This hat is too big for me." "It was too wet for us to go out." etc. etc.

Comment: As well, *like* can have either *for* + object + infinitive or a direct object + infinitive. It'd be a tighter comparison to compare to a verb like *prefer*; "prefer for you + infinitive" is much less standard than "like for you + infinitive."

Comment: ...as pointed out in linguist John Lawler's answer to that linked question, the verb "to like" ***allows** a For-complementizer on its subject, if it's different from the subject of "like"* (but as with "intend, prefer, want", etc., the word "for" is often "deleted" in such usages). So that's a special case, only loosely related to your other example where "for" *can't* be deleted.

Comment: The "for" in your first example is part of the for-to complementizer, which converts a clause into the complement of some suitable verb.  The "for" in the second example, however, is the preposition "for".